# Error: Failed to start the transport 'LongPolling': Error: No Connection with that ID: Status code '404'

Tags: azure-web-app-service, signalr, signalr.client, asp.net-core-signalr

I have created a signalr selfhosted webapp service that connects to on prem signalr service using hybrid connection. This self hosted service then broadcast the changes to front end and back to on prem signalR.  The self hosted service is fronted by a front door.

[image: diagram]

Everything works fine locally with long polling (front door doesn't support websockets), but doesn't work when deployed in Azure. Error: Failed to start the transport 'LongPolling': Error: No Connection with that ID: Status code '404'

Anything i am missing?

Comment: Can you collect web traces of failed connections?https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/diagnostics?view=aspnetcore-3.1#network-traces

Comment: @Chaodeng: got the har file, can't seem to upload it here. I resolved the issue partly by turning on ARR on the app service but still no luck when app service is behind the Azure front door

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enabled the clientAffinity on the app service and that did the magic. Also on Azure front door removed the host header on the backend [image]
[image: app service]

Comment: Hey, I have the same LongPolling error. How do you remove the host header on the backend? I was able to turn on the Application Request Routing as it shows here https://edi.wang/post/2020/11/2/how-to-enable-application-request-routing-on-azure-app-service.